# Verificar se valor da lista "1" contém lista "2"

Tags: python

Eu tenho duas listas:

```
track_list = ['iphone 6', 'iphone 5', 'moto x2', 'galaxy s6']

tweets_data = ['Eu queria um iphone 6 sérião', 
               'nao gostei do moto x2', 
               'iphone 5 é coisa do passado']
```

Quero verificar se os valores de `track_list` aparecem em `tweets_data`, se aparecerem, imprime na tela tais valores.

Também gostaria de saber como obter a *string* que mais se repete nas listas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como [mencionado pelo Dherik](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93327/6454), existem outras formas de fazer isso em Python, uma delas é usar a [função `itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) que é equivalente a *loops aninhados*, veja um exemplo:

```
from itertools import product

track_list = ['iphone 6', 'iphone 5', 'moto x2', 'galaxy s6']
tweet_data = ['Eu queria um iphone 6 seriao', 
               'nao gostei do moto x2', 
               'iphone 5 e coisa do passado', 
               'abc123']

for track, tweet in product(track_list, tweet_data):
    if track in tweet:
        print (track)
```

[Veja a **`demonstração`**](https://repl.it/BRwH)

Uma outra forma é [comprimir a lista](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
track_list = ['iphone 6', 'iphone 5', 'moto x2', 'galaxy s6']
tweet_data = ['Eu queria um iphone 6 seriao', 
               'nao gostei do moto x2', 
               'iphone 6 e coisa do passado', 
               'abc123']

tracks = ([track for tweet in tweet_data for track in track_list if track in tweet])

print (tracks)
# ['iphone 6', 'moto x2', 'iphone 6']
```

[Veja a **`demonstração`**](https://repl.it/BRwJ)

Para saber qual palavra aparece mais numa string pode-se usar a [função `most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) da [subclasse `collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), veja um exemplo:

```
from collections import Counter

track_list = ['iphone 6', 'iphone 5', 'moto x2', 'galaxy s6']
tweet_data = ['Eu queria um iphone 6 seriao', 
               'nao gostei do moto x2', 
               'iphone 5 e coisa do passado', 
               'abc123']

tracks = ([track for tweet in tweet_data for track in track_list if track in tweet])

contador = Counter(tracks).most_common()

for palavra, qtd in contador:
    print ("A palavra {0} aparece {1} vez(es)".format(palavra, qtd))
# A palavra iphone 5 aparece 1 vez(es)
# A palavra iphone 6 aparece 1 vez(es)
# A palavra moto x2 aparece 1 vez(es)
```

[Veja a **`demonstração`**](https://repl.it/BRw0)

Answer (score 4):

você pode fazer assim:

```
    #LISTA 1
    track_list = ['iphone 6', 'iphone 5', 'moto x2', 'galaxy s6']

    #LISTA 2
    tweets_data = ['Eu queria um iphone 6 sérião', 'nao gostei do moto x2', 'iphone 5 é coisa do passado']

    for track in track_list:
        for tweet in tweets_data:
            if track in tweet:
                print(track)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
track_list = ['iphone 6', 'iphone 5', 'moto x2', 'galaxy s6']
tweets_data = ['Eu queria um iphone 6 seriao', 'nao gostei do moto x2', 'iphone 5 e coisa do passado']

for tweet in tweets_data:
    for track in track_list:
        if track in tweet:
            print(tweet)
```

Existem formas diferentes de fazer isto com python. Esta eu considero a mais simples de entender.

Exemplo: https://repl.it/BRuh/1

Comment: realizei esta configuração conforme informado mais nao chegou a imprimir valor, algum, conseguiria te mostrar mais a fundo meu codigo?